# How to fix TextWatcher on orientation change?

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I want to write a validator for multiple `editText`'s using `TextWatcher`.

I already have method to validate if the data written by user is correct.
And also added validation to check if `editText` is empty. But here is where it's not working as I would like to. 
This `TextWatcher` is also activated when phone changes orientation and I don't want this to happen. I want it work only when user deletes data from `editText`.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
final public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

@Override
final public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

@Override
final public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    if(textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        textView.setError("Can't be empty");
        ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
    } else {
        validate(textView, text);
    }
}
```

And the `validate` part in fragment look like this:

```
editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(new ParameterValidator(editText2_5) {
    @Override
    public void validate(TextView textView, String text) {
        double parDouble = Double.parseDouble(Tab2Fragment.editText2_5.getText().toString());
        if (parDouble < sth_min) {
            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_min_value) + " " + sth_min);
            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
        } else if (parDouble > sth_max) {
            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_max_value) + " " + sth_max);
            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
        } else {
            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = true;
        }         
    }
});
```

Question is how can I make it not triggering on orientation change?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        switch (newConfig.orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(null);
                break;

            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
//                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(null);

                // ============= OR =============

//                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(new ParameterValidator(editText2_5) {
//                    @Override
//                    public void validate(TextView textView, String text) {
//                        double parDouble = Double.parseDouble(Tab2Fragment.editText2_5.getText().toString());
//                        if (parDouble < sth_min) {
//                            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_min_value) + " " + sth_min);
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
//                        } else if (parDouble > sth_max) {
//                            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_max_value) + " " + sth_max);
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
//                        } else {
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = true;
//                        }
//                    }
//                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but if I understand it correctly, with this code validation will only work in one orientation and what I want is to work in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var doesDeviceTitled = false
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    doesDeviceTitled = when (newConfig.orientation) {
        Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE -> {
            true
        }
        else -> {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The above code was in Kotlin

then after wrap validation using this boolean variable.

```
editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(new ParameterValidator(editText2_5) {
@Override
public void validate(TextView textView, String text) {
   if(!doesDeviceTitled){
     //Your validation code here.
    }
  }});
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but like in @Dheeraj answer I think it will work only in one orientation. The goal is to block from triggering on orientation change the first part of the code which checks if textView is empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so now as I think, you need to declare `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your `<activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` and remove this:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        switch (newConfig.orientation) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(null);
                break;

            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
//                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(null);

                // ============= OR =============

//                editText2_5.addTextChangedListener(new ParameterValidator(editText2_5) {
//                    @Override
//                    public void validate(TextView textView, String text) {
//                        double parDouble = Double.parseDouble(Tab2Fragment.editText2_5.getText().toString());
//                        if (parDouble < sth_min) {
//                            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_min_value) + " " + sth_min);
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
//                        } else if (parDouble > sth_max) {
//                            textView.setError(getString(R.string.err_max_value) + " " + sth_max);
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = false;
//                        } else {
//                            ParametersFrag.isCorrect = true;
//                        }
//                    }
//                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```